# SQL Server OPENDATASOURCE and IBM AS400

Tags: sql-server, ibm-midrange

Our system (SQL Server) needs to connect and get data from an old IBM AS400. We need a way to get data from the AS400 using OPENDATASOURCE.

Can anyone who succeeded with this point me in the right direction on how to use it (ODBC drivers, syntax etc...)?

We are now using a linked server but due to the fact that the client reboots our server every night the linked server is dropped and all our processes go on error until it reconnects correctly, so is not an option here.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Can't you use SSIS option instead ?

Comment: No , we just use the data from tha AS400 as a lookup  to complete missing values.

Comment: If linked server is rebooted, you would loose connection anyway, irrespective of query you are trying to merge/insert. I would suggest to create a staging table and insert data into staging from AS400 and eventually perform a `merge`